# How to wait on the FileChooser selection?

Tags: java, path, selection, wait, filechooser

What I want to do is to use the `FileChooser` to select a path.

AFTER the selection, the path should by used by the following instance.

My problem is how to force everything to wait on the path, because otherwise the program is just running without waiting.

```
    //GUI 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Window");
    FileChooser panel = new FileChooser();

    frame.addWindowListener(
      new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
          System.exit(0);
          }
        }
      );
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
    frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    if(panel.getPath() == null){

    }
    String path = panel.getPath();

    //some additional stuff that does not need any pathinformation
    .......
    //next step calculation which runs without waiting 
    Calculation calc = new Calculation();
    calc.run(path);
```

Thanks in advance

P.S.

 this is what my ActionListner contains

```
        if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Cancel was selected");
        }
        else if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "

                + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
        System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
                + chooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }
```

Comment: You want to read about "modal" dialogs. See here for example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Do you mean this one?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: @JürgenK. I think they mean [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of an even listener:

```
panel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getActionCommand() == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = panel.getSelectedFile();
            // Do what you want with selected file  
        } else {
            // When user pressed close or "X" in the corder.
        }
   }
});
```

In place of `String path = panel.getPath();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is, the `JFileChooser` is running in it's own thread already. That's why `panel.getPath()` isn't working. So handling the file selection in a different thread would most likely be the easiest way.

Comment: Actually  panel.getPath() is working. The program just doesn't wait on the result

Comment: @JürgenK. I know it doesn't wait. That's what I meant by **not working**. The reason is doesn't wait is because of the Threading problem I explained. One way to get around this problem is to create the event listener. Another way (not recommended) would be to have something like: `while ((path = panel.getPath()) != null) {}`. This however will bring more problems than it is worth.